# Authenticating against WooCommerce API with customer usernamer/Password

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, woocommerce-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

We are re-building an Easy Order Wordpress plugin with VueJs, that uses WooCommerce REST API.

Current flow: The customer go to the website and do a login with email/password, with the login done, the user can go to 'Easy Order' link to access the plugin and then the user get all products categories, subcategories and products. the user can add/remove products into his cart.

What we are trying to reach: We are changing the plugin to use the WooCommerce REST API, but there is no way to access the data with a customer email/password login in WooCommerce REST API, the Wordpress login does not work at all with WooCommerce REST API.

Has anybody here with the same problem that can give insights about that?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Simple JWT Login plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-jwt-login/).
It provides additional endpoints for logging in customers as well as generating unique JSON web tokens. I am using it in my react native app to login customers as well as registering new users.